# Adding a slideshow using webkit only showing the second image

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, slideshow

It's not moving at all. Changing the size of the picture shows the previous, or next one though, no animations, or transitions occur. Here's the HTML and CSS controlling it. It's kind of long, since I read it in a weird way.

HTML:

```
 <div class="slides-control" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 3861px; left: -1287px; transition-property: -webkit-transform; -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; transition-duration: 600ms; -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; transform: translate3d(-1287px, 0px, 0px); -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1287px, 0px, 0px);"><ul class="slides-container" style="display: block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; list-style: none; position: relative; height: 100%; opacity: 1; transition-property: all; -webkit-transition-property: all; transition-duration: 0s; -webkit-transition-duration: 0s; transition-timing-function: ease; -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;">

    <li style="display: block; left: 1287px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 1287px; top: 0px; z-index: 2;"><img src="http://tinyurl.com/nxuqz5w" style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -452px; z-index: -1; max-width: none; height: 1287px; width: 1287px;"></li>

    <li style="display: block; left: 2574px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 1287px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><img src="http://tinyurl.com/oexohmp" style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -452px; z-index: -1; max-width: none; height: 1287px; width: 1287px;"></li>

    <li style="display: none; left: 1287px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 1287px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><img src="http://tinyurl.com/qb5pg56" style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -452px; z-index: -1; max-width: none; height: 1287px; width: 1287px;"></li>
```

The rest of the code is in the jfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/39pwb98w/

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if I'm missing something here but is there any script to drive the slideshow?
CSS transition only moves from one state to another, so if there is no script to update the state it will not change.
Your positioning style has probably been applied already, which would explain why you are seeing slide number 2.

You can chain transitions together and loop which might get an effect you desire, though it might be a little too hard coded for my linking.

See here for transition iteration: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp

See here for transition chaining: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp